# Determine if there is folder on one of the subfolder in any level c#

Tags: c#, find, filesystems, subdirectory

Is there any efficient way on C# to determine whether exists subfolder with name 'sub' in any level of the folder.

Means, given path I would like to determine if there is any level on the subtree of path which contais folder 'sub'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Directory.GetDirectories()` or `Directory.EnumerateDirectories()` methods, specifying that includes the current directory and all its subdirectories in a search operation:

```
var subDirs =  Directory.GetDirectories("ROOT PATH", "sub", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```